# How do I post a viewmodel where I only change part of the viewmodel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am making a project that is a movie database with MVC and an API.
A user must be able to comment and score on a movie. If I want to display the movie I use a Viewmodel named MovieVM where you can see the properties of the movie and comments that have already been made. I also have a small form there where a user can make a new comment. Can I post the comment alone? Do I need to post the whole viewmodel and give the info back again?

```
@model MMDB_WebApp.Models.MovieVM
@{
    string Id = null;
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";

    if (TempData.ContainsKey("StateData"))
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> stateData = (Dictionary<string, string>)TempData["StateData"];

        Id = stateData["_Id"];
    }

    TempData.Keep();
}

<div>
    <h4>MovieVM</h4>
    <hr />
    @if (Model.Poster != null)
    {
        <img class="float-right" src="~/images/Posters/@Model.Poster" asp-append-version="true">
    }
    else
    {
        <img class="float-right" src="~/images/Posters/not_available.jpg">
    }
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DirectorId)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DirectorId)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DirectorName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DirectorName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Actors)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <ul>
                @foreach (var Actor in Model.Actors)
                {
                <li>
                    <img src="~/images/Avatars/no_avatar.png" />
                    <a asp-action="">@Actor.Name</a>
                </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="row bootstrap snippets">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
            <div class="comment-wrapper">
                <div class="card card-info">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Comment panel
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form asp-action="comment" method="post">
                            <input hidden asp-for="NewComment.Date" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                            <input hidden asp-for="NewComment.MovieId" value="@Model.Id" />
                            <input hidden asp-for="NewComment.UserId" value="@Id" />
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="write a comment..." rows="3" asp-for="NewComment.CommentText"></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-right">Post</button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <hr>
                        </form>

                        @if (Model.Comments.Count() != 0)
                        {
                            <ul class="media-list">
                                @foreach (var Comment in Model.Comments)
                                {
                                    <li class="media">

                                        @if (Comment.UserAvatar != null)
                                        {
                                            <img src="~/images/Avatars/@Comment.UserAvatar" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user profile image">
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <img src="~/images/Avatars/no_avatar.png" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user profile image">
                                        }
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <span class="text-muted float-right">
                                                <small class="text-muted">@Comment.Date</small>
                                            </span>
                                            <strong class="text-success">@Comment.UserName</strong>
                                            <p>
                                                @Comment.CommentText
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                }
                            </ul>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p>No comments yet</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
public class MoviePutVM
    {

        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "title is required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("releaseDate")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("poster")]
        [DisplayName("PosterName")]
        public string Poster { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("posterFile")]
        [DisplayName("UploadImage")]
        public IFormFile PosterFile { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("directorId")]
        public int? DirectorId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("directorName")]
        public string DirectorName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("newComment")]
        public CommentVM NewComment { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("actors")]
        public virtual ICollection<ActorMovieVM> Actors { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("comments")]
        public virtual ICollection<CommentVM> Comments { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("votes")]
        public virtual ICollection<VotesVM> Votes { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("genres")]
        public virtual ICollection<MovieGenresVM> Genres { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CommentVM
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("commentText")]
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        //Relationships
        [JsonPropertyName("userId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("userAvatar")]
        public string UserAvatar { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("movieId")]
        public int? MovieId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You should post comment using Ajax instead posting full page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I post the comment alone? Do I need to post the whole viewmodel
>   and give the info back again?

You can pass the comment model alone to the controller by value, and you don't need to pass the entire viewmodel, or even you don't need the NewComment field.

You only need to ensure that **the name attribute** of the corresponding field in the submitted form is consistent with your **comment model**,
pass the required information to the comment and store them in the comment table.

```
   <form asp-action="comment" method="post">
                            <input hidden name="Date" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                            <input hidden name="MovieId" value="@Model.Id" />
                            <input hidden name="UserId" value="@Id" />
                            <textarea  name="CommentText" class="form-control" placeholder="write a comment..." rows="3" ></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-right">Post</button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <hr>
  </form>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult comment(CommentVM newcomment)
        {
           //save this new comment to the comment table which related to the movie table.
            _context.CommentVM.Add(newcomment);
            _context.SaveChanges(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]